# How to exit a Double ArrayList's While Loop with a negative int value check?

Tags: java, arraylist, int, double

This is a Shopping List program.  The user enters a value like $2.00 for each item on her list. But if she wants to exit this part of the program, she enters "-1"

I understand this Double ArrayList and the int "-1" are "incomparable types," as the compiler error message reads.

Any suggestions for int "-1" exit code concerning a Double ArrayList?

Thank you, please.

Here's my code:

```
 ArrayList<Double> priceInputAnswer = new ArrayList<Double>()                

                {
                    System.out.print("Please enter an item price, or -1 to exit: $");
                    Scanner numberReader = new Scanner (System.in); 
                    while (numberReader.hasNextDouble())
                        {
                        priceInputAnswer.add(numberReader.nextDouble());

                        }

                                while (priceInputAnswer != -1)
```

}

Comment: `priceInputAnswer` isn't an `int`; just logically, you wouldn't compare a list to something that's not a list. It's the proverbial case of comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift help.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual code doesn't seem to compile.

Anyway, you can do things in two steps.
1) Store the value from the scanner in a `priceInput` variable
2) Use it in the while statement :  `while (priceInput != -1)`

The `do/while` form is not necessarily the best form for your need.
You should write something like that :

```
double priceInput = -1;
do {
    priceInput = numberReader.nextDouble();
    if (priceInput != -1) {
        priceInputAnswer.add(priceInput);
    }
} while (priceInput != -1);
```

A `while` with a input retrieved before it seems more natural as it avoids the `if` statement in the loop:

```
double priceInput = numberReader.nextDouble();
while (priceInput != -1) {
    priceInputAnswer.add(priceInput);
    priceInput = numberReader.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift and most detailed help. Especially the finer points of Java code-writing best practices.   Your suggestions are of course working and helping me hurdle what had been a compiler impasse.  And as well enabling me to learn better how to simplify my code, as my professor has suggested.